# Non deterministic behaviour while using libtensorflow with C API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to run inference on a TensorFlow model with the **libtensorflow** library from a program written in **C/C++**. The C library is not well documented but I figured out how to do thanks to some tutorials I could find on the Web. A *minimal program* reproducing my problem can be found below. It basically loads the model from disk, checks the dimensions of the input and output tensors and feed some data into.

As I trained and tested the model in Python, I know exactly what is the expected output for a given input. Normally, for the input set up in this minimal program, the output has to be this vector:

```
0.0061
0.0349
0.0843
0.7584
0.0767
0.0320
0.0073
```

and this is the result I find back from my C/C++ program, ..., sometimes. But **this is not deterministic at all**. It works well maybe 1 time out of 5. The other times I just got wrong values like this:

```
1.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

I can understand there is something wrong in my program but I have hard time to explain why I get this stochastic behaviour.

I tested this program on different machines, both on Windows 10 and Linux. The library I use is the one that can be downloaded [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c), **version 2.4 CPU only**. In case of the code is not enough, I also uploaded my model [here](http://www.genid.eu/tensorflow/Model.zip).

I would truly appreciate if someone could pinpoint what is wrong in this code.

```
#include <string>
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"

static void NoOpDeallocator (void* /*data*/, size_t /*a*/, void* /*b*/)
{
}

int InputIndicesToIndex (int x, int y, int z)
{
    int index = x * 7 * 4 + y * 4 + z;
    return index;
}

int main (void)
{
    const char* path = "./Model";
    const char* input_name = "serving_default_input_1";
    const char* output_name = "StatefulPartitionedCall";

    // Load graph
    TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph ();
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus ();
    TF_Buffer* runOptions = nullptr;
    TF_SessionOptions* options = TF_NewSessionOptions ();

    const char* tags = "serve";
    int ntags = 1;

    TF_Session* session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel (options, runOptions, path, &tags, ntags, graph, nullptr, status);
    if (TF_GetCode (status) != TF_OK)
    {
        printf ("\n[ERROR] While loading TensorFlow saved model, got: %s", TF_Message (status));
        return -1;
    }

    // Check graph input and output
    TF_Output input = {TF_GraphOperationByName (graph, input_name), 0};
    if (input.oper == nullptr)
    {
        printf ("\nCould not find operation name in graph, got message: \"%s\"", TF_Message (status));
        return -1;
    }

    TF_Output output = {TF_GraphOperationByName (graph, output_name), 0};
    if (output.oper == nullptr)
    {
        printf ("\nCould not find operation name in graph, got message: \"%s\"", TF_Message (status));
        return -1;
    }

    if (TF_OperationOutputType (input) != TF_FLOAT || TF_OperationOutputType (output) != TF_FLOAT)
    {
        printf ("\nUnexpected data type");
        return -1;
    }

    // Check input shape
    int64_t dims [16];
    int numDims = TF_GraphGetTensorNumDims (graph, input, status);
    TF_GraphGetTensorShape (graph, input, dims, numDims, status);
    if (TF_GetCode (status) != TF_OK) {
        printf ("\nCould not retrieve tensor shape, got message: \"%s\"", TF_Message (status));
        return -1;
    }
    if (numDims != 4 || dims [0] != -1 || dims [1] != 6 || dims [2] != 7 || dims [3] != 4)
    {
        printf ("\nUnexpected input tensor dimensions");
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind data array to graph input
    float inputData [1 * 6 * 7 * 4];
    dims [0] = 1;
    TF_Tensor* inputTensor = TF_NewTensor (TF_FLOAT, dims, numDims, inputData, sizeof (float) * 6 * 7 * 4, &NoOpDeallocator, 0);
    if (inputTensor == nullptr)
    {
        printf ("\nCould not create input tensor");
        return -1;
    }

    // Check output shape
    numDims = TF_GraphGetTensorNumDims (graph, output, status);
    TF_GraphGetTensorShape (graph, output, dims, numDims, status);
    if (TF_GetCode (status) != TF_OK) {
        printf ("Could not retrieve tensor shape, got message: \"%s\"", TF_Message (status));
        return -1;
    }
    if (numDims != 2 || dims [0] != -1 || dims [1] != 7)
    {
        printf ("\nUnexpected output tensor dimensions");
        return -1;
    }

    // Feed input with some data
    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y ++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x ++)
        {
            inputData [InputIndicesToIndex (y, x, 0)] = 0.0f;
            inputData [InputIndicesToIndex (y, x, 1)] = 1.0f;
            inputData [InputIndicesToIndex (y, x, 2)] = 0.0f;
            inputData [InputIndicesToIndex (y, x, 3)] = 0.0f;
        }
    }
    
    // Run the session to compute the output
    TF_Tensor* outputTensor;
    TF_SessionRun (session, nullptr, &input, &inputTensor, 1, &output, &outputTensor, 1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, status);
    if (TF_GetCode (status) != TF_OK)
    {
        printf ("\n[ERROR] Could not run graph inference, got %s", TF_Message (status));
        return -1;
    }

    // Read out the result
    float* outputData = (float*) TF_TensorData (outputTensor);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i ++)
        printf ("\n%f", outputData [i]);
    
    if ((int) (outputData [3] * 1000.0f) != 758) {
        printf ("\n[ERROR] Unexpected inference result");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf ("\n[OK] Inference ran fine");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I continued to investigate myself after having posted this question and I could finally figure out what happens. I write my explanation here in the hope it could help someone one day.

The problem comes from an undocumented behaviour of the libtensorflow library (as far as it is possible for an undocumented library). While reading the include files I discovered an additional way to create a tensor, by using `TF_AllocateTensor` instead of `TF_NewTensor`. I tried this function and then it worked finally like a charm.

*However, it is worth to understand why.*

By using `TF_NewTensor`, you basically ask TensorFlow to create a new tensor wrapping a data buffer that **you** provide. But the problem is: TensorFlow **may decide or not** to use your data buffer or to **potentially reallocate it elsewhere**. One can say in its favour that *it warns you by calling the deallocating function that you have to provide*. But it can get completely unnoticed as all the tuto I found simply provide an empty deallocating function (see `NoOpDeallocator`  in the code).

This behaviour is triggered by some memory management mechanism in the internal library machinery, so you must always get ready for that to happen. This means that you **cannot** do things in this order:

1. Allocate a buffer
2. Call `TF_NewTensor`
3. Fill in your buffer with some data,

because TensorFlow may not use your buffer by the time you fill it in. Therefore you have to fill it **before** calling `TF_NewTensor`. Then if you have to modify it, you have to call `TF_TensorData` to be sure to have the good address in hand.

The second option consists in asking TensorFlow to make the data allocation itself by using `TF_AllocateTensor`. This is a far better option in my case as the data buffer could be moved anyway.